# Why is my basic javascript not running?

Tags: javascript, html

I can usually get this to work inline, but  I want to learn how to properly link to other pages for bigger projects. Here it is:

```js
var numberOne = document.getElementById('num1');
var numberTwo = document.getElementById('num2');
var submitButton = document.getElementById('submitButton');
var theAnswerText = document.getElementById('theAnswer');

submitButton.addEventListener("click", add);
numberOne.addEventListener("click", function() {
  alert("Hello! World");
});

function add() {

  alert("I am in add()");
  var num1 = numberOne.value;
  var num2 = numberTwo.value;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script language=javascript type="text/javascript" src=javascript.js>
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div style=display:inline;>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Num 1</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id=num1 type=text />
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <p>Num 2</p>
        </td>
        <td>
          <input id=num2 type=text />
        </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>
          <input id=submitButton type=button value=submit />
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>

  <p id=theAnswer>The answer is:</p>


  <body>

</html>
```

I started html/css/js about 6 days ago, so I'm very new. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Move the `script` tag to the end of the `body` tag or wrap the code that is accessing _DOM_ elements inside the `DOMContentLoaded` callback

Comment: Are you putting your script tag in the `<head>`? If so, your javascript is probably firing before the DOM (html) has loaded, so it can't find the elements that you're looking for. Try putting your script at the end of the `<body>` tag.

Comment: Mr. Tushar and Mr. Nick, can you tell me why the js file exectutes prior to the DOM loading? I figure since it is waiting for my even to occur it wouldn't fire until then? I tried it your way and it works great :D Thank you again you two!

Comment: It is working correctly https://jsfiddle.net/DIRTY_SMITH/7a7m84ea/3/

Comment: I ended up changing my mind on how I wanted it to display a couple times, and I just didn't change the code.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith So you base someone's level of professional understanding off of how many imaginary points they have on an arbitrary website? How about you analyze why I said you lacked understanding, and correct your opinion.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith You created a fiddle with a completely different structure than what the OP posted here and then you say "It is working correctly". That is not the way to go. You should point out what you changed and why yours is working. Then it would make a good answer.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith By that logic, I know 8x as much as you.  Nick's right.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith, The fiddle works because the jsfiddle internally makes sure anything written in the javascript actually runs after `onload`.

Comment: @Ozan not always, that is just the annoying default option from the left hand menu :/

Comment: I agree there seems to be some discontinuity, it doesn't necessarily bring into question anyone's knowledge but it causes confusion. For example, why add `theAnswerText` and not use it, firing `alert(num3)` instead? I mean either don't include `theAnswerText` code, or use it, with or without the `alert(num3)` that's a matter of taste. Not saying this is a fundamental problem to have unused code, but it can be seen as contributing to the discourse over the usefulness of it. I do suggest however that we try to avoid personal attacks and take individual input with a grain of salt.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith thank you but its unfair to say the last part. Regardless of how it is generally perceived by the masses, everyone has a reasonable case in mind when expressing themselves. Some do it well, some not so much, sometimes it becomes confrontational but ultimately the goal is to solve a problem, that should be the focus. Nothing stifles progress more than fear of criticism. Constructive case points will always yield progress while outright attacks, hardly help anything. </soapbox>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is recommended and good practice to put `attribute` values inside quotes.

```
<input id=num1 type=text />
```

The following would be the recommended syntax.

```
<input id='num1' type="text" />
//Please note that single quote and double quote both works.
```

Secondly, even after you correct your syntax, your javascript would not work. Because **you load your script before the html body is rendered**. The element you are trying to select in your script are not on the page yet. There are two simple solutions to this common problem

- Put your `script` at the end of the `body` tag, therefor making sure all the dom elements are already rendered.
- Use [onload event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onload) to make sure the document is loaded and all dom elements are rendered before you try to select any dom elements.

Comment: Technically, HTML attributes don't require quotation marks; you may want to remove that from your answer.

Comment: I am so used to the use of quotes that I was thinking them mandatory. Edited it. Thanks for pointing out.